# pandas.read_csv() returning a ParserError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Today I turn my attention to the wonderful world of `pandas`. I am trying to read a .csv file, which is an easy task, but when I pass in the file (right here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grammakov/USA-cities-and-states/master/us_cities_states_counties.csv), it gives me this mess:

`pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 9, saw 5`

I have tried setting `delimiter` to an empty string, setting it to a variable, and declaring the type `pd.Dataframe`.

Comment: Show ur csv file. It clearly says in the ParseError that the problem is in the CSV and not in ur code

Comment: The csv is in the link.

Comment: THe error is saying the csv is the problem, but I am not so sure now

Comment: Do you need more traceback?

Comment: "setting delimiter to an empty string" is your problem. The file you linked is delimited with a pipe character, `'|'`, so when you use anything else it parses it weird

Comment: yup I just realized that too man

Comment: so what you are saying is to set `delimiter` to `|`?

Comment: yep pretty much

Answer (score 3):

Use delimiter `|`, by adding either `sep='|'` or `delimiter='|'` to `.read_csv()` (both parameters mean the same thing). like

```
pd.read_csv(r'File_path', sep='|')
```

Comment: @Arandomcoder i ran this code `from pandas import read_csv as rc
>>> rc("data.csv",sep='|')` , it did work

Comment: The `delimiter` and `sep` parameters are synonymous. Use one or the other but not both.

Comment: @tdelaney yes, just used `sep` for brevity